# Repository Pattern With Unity

Tags: c#, wpf, unity-game-engine, win-universal-app

I am very new to Repository patterns and therefore wanted to ask if my current (simplified) model is correct, or it needs additional modifications.

**Background:**

I have a Universal Windows Platform application, which has a main window. Here I display simple list of `Customers` (only Name, Surname & DateOfBirth).

Then I have a button, where user can **Edit** selected customer's properties (this will navigate to a new DetailPage.xaml).

**Setup:**

This is how I have set-up my repository class & interface:

```
public interface ICustomerRepository
{
    void AddCustomer(Customer newCustomer);
    void RemoveCustomer(Customer item);
    List<Customer> GetCustomers();
    void LoadCustomers(string sFilePath);
}

///Class Definition
public class CustomerRepository : ICustomerRepository
{
    private List<Customer> _customers;

    public void AddCustomer(Customer newCustomer)
    {
        if(newCustomer!=null)
        {
            if (!_customers.Contains(newCustomer))
                _customers.Add(newCustomer);
        }
    }

    public CustomerRepository()
    {
        LoadCustomers("defaultPath");
    }

    public void RemoveCustomer(Customer item)
    {
        if (item != null)
            _customers.Remove(item);
    }

    public void LoadCustomers(string sPath)
    {
        //would load data from a file here
        _customers = new List<Customer>()
        {
            new Customer() {ID = 1, Name ="Janko", Surname= "Hrasko", DateOfBirth = DateTime.Now },
            new Customer() {ID = 2, Name ="Jozef", Surname= "Mrkvicka", DateOfBirth = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10) },
            new Customer() {ID = 1, Name ="Jozko", Surname= "Stefanovic", DateOfBirth = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-50) }
        };
    }

    public List<Customer> GetCustomers()
    {
        if (_customers == null || _customers.Count == 0)
            LoadCustomers("defaultPath");

        return new List<Customer>(_customers);
    }
}
```

Under my App.xaml.cs, under `OnInitializeAsync` I have Registered this Repository in a following manner:

```
_Container.RegisterType<ICustomerRepository, CustomerRepository>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

In my `MainWindowViewModel` I have a collection (which I display on a page), which looks like following:

```
    public ObservableCollection<Customer> col_customers
    {
        get
        {
            return new ObservableCollection<Customer>(_customerRepository.GetCustomers());
        }
    }
```

**Question:**

Is this the correct way to implement a repository in my application?

Comment: does it fit you? do you have any problems using it? just try

Comment: There are no problems, everything works as expected. The reason why I am asking is, that I am not sure if I have not missed anything crucial there?

Comment: it's very hard to answer your question. it will be primarily opinion-based. so, i advice you to try this implementation, and watch for actual problems. and you'll have them - ask a question. you need something to begin and this code is better than more i saw :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please tell me, what problems I might encounter?

Comment: You can get memory leaks from `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager`. Read more about lifetime managers (try to use HierarhicalLifetimeManager).

Comment: Or having performance issue on loading up ur ViewModel when you have tons of Customer